# How to get a sum of the two lists?

Tags: python

There are two lists of the same length.
How to get a third list with elements are equal to the sum of the corresponding elements of the two original lists?

For example:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 10, 7]
l2 = [0, 6, 1, 2]
l = [1, 8, 11, 9]
```

Comment: Should the third element in `l` be 11?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have to do some operations for elements with same indexes with two (or more) lists of the same size, it is a good idea to use `zip()` function.

This function takes two equal-length collections, and merges them together in pairs.

You can find out some fundamental information in [*Python* docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

To solve your problem you should try:

```
l = [x+y for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]
```

Comment: Some explanation might be nice--a description of what `zip` means, or at least a link to the docs, and maybe a link to list comprehensions in the tutorial in case he's never seen one.

Answer (score 1):

With [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), it's something like this:

```
import itertools

[i + j for i, j in itertools.izip(l1, l2)]
```

You can think of`itertools.izip(l1, l2)` as something like a sequence that consists of pairs of members from the two original sequences.